# Why dataframe.drop_duplicates('name') is correct, dataframe.drop_duplicates('age') can't work?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two columns, 'name' and 'code'. These columns has duplicate values. When I use  df.drop_duplicates to deal with the column 'name', it is correct and the duplicate values was cleared. But when I deal with the column 'code', it does not work. Anyone knows why? Thank you.

The format of code is '0100'...'266377390'
The format of name is '王二，张三'

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['code'],keep='first')
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'],keep='first')
```

Comment: Since you are working with non-ascii characters, can it be encoding issue?

Comment: are you sure you're looking at the correct column names: in the heading you speak about column 'age', in the code example you mention column 'code'?